# How to use headers and page breaks properly while generating word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, page-break

I'm confused how to use headers in combination with page breaks properly. I have report in word format I'm generating using VBA from excel. Basic structure should be like:

page 1

- header
- text
- text
- page break

page 2

- text
- text
- text
- text

Result I'm getting is like this:

page 1

- header
- text
- text

page 2

- page break
- empty page
- empty page
- empty page

page 3

- text
- text
- text
- text

Page break is created using this part of code:

```
'Launches word application
Set Wapp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
With Wapp
    With .Selection
        'New paragraph & line
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeText St1
        .TypeText St2
        'Collapses selection
        .Collapse Direction:=0 'Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        'New page
        .InsertBreak Type:=7 'Type:=wdPageBreak
    End With
End With
```

I have tried to change Type to 4 or 2, it then creates no extra page, but then header appears in second page, and I don't want that. Also I tried to add this line while creating header, but it does not seem to work:

```
With Doc.PageSetup
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
End With
```

Then I was thinking maybe it is possible to delete empty page by detecting paragraph with page break and wrote this code:

```
'Procedure will check if there are blank pages and remove them
Sub DeleteLastPageBreak(Wapp As Object)
Dim i As Long
Dim Doc As Word.Document
Dim P As Paragraph
    'Creates reference to Word document
    Set Doc = Wapp.ActiveDocument
    For Each P In Doc.Content.Paragraphs
        If P.Range.Characters.Count = 1 Then
            If P.Range.Characters(1) = vbFormFeed Then
                MsgBox "paragraph found"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It seems that it cant detect page break. What exactly am I doing wrong and how to achieve my desired result?

Comment: You haven't inserted a page break. Look up the break types in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbreaktype) and you will see that you have inserted a section break.

Comment: Original code use wdPageBreak  or 7 and yes I used same documentation, just mentioned that I have tried 2 and 4 also.

Comment: Don't use Createobject at this stage, use a reference to Word so that you get access to intellisense for the Word object.  (Tools.References scroll down and make sure the check box next to Microsoft Word Object XX.XX is checked.).  Are you confusing Headers and Headings?  If you do want a Header then these are a property of the Section object.  Pages don't really exist in Word, they are an artefact generated by the printer driver.  Work with sections and life will be much much easier.

Comment: Conversely, if you're using a Paragraph Style for a heading (as you should), and you want that heading to start on a new page, give that Style the 'page break before' attribute). That way you don't need code to insert the page breaks.

Comment: Inserting a page break will not, by itself, result in an empty page in your document. Inserting certain types of section break, wdSectionBreakEvenPage (4) or wdSectionBreakOddPage (5), can. Only add a section break if you are making changes that affect page layout, which includes headers and footers.

Answer (score -2):

The following code, which uses the Word reference (Early bound Word object) may be helpful to illustrate principles.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

    Dim myWord As Word.Application
    Set myWord = New Word.Application
    
    myWord.Visible = True
    myWord.Activate
    
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Set myDoc = myWord.Documents.Add
    
    'Information for first section
    With myDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)

        ' At this point there is only 1 section in the document
        With .Sections.Last
        
            With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            
                .Paragraphs.Item(1).Range.Text = "This is paragraph1 in the header"
                
            End With
        
            With .Range.Paragraphs.Item(1).Range
            
                .Style = myDoc.Styles(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1)
                .Text = "MyHeadingText "
                .InsertParagraphAfter
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .Text = "Paragraph 2"
                .InsertParagraphAfter
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .Text = "paragraph 3"
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                'start a new section with next page enabled
                .InsertBreak Type:=WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                With .Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
                
                    .LinkToPrevious = False
                    .Range.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = "This is header in section 2 which is on a new page"
                    
                End With
                
                .Style = myDoc.Styles(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1)
                .Text = "MyHeadingText in section 2 (on a new page)"
                .InsertParagraphAfter
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .Text = "Paragraph 2"
                .InsertParagraphAfter
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                .Text = "paragraph 3"
                .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            
            End With
            
        End With
        
    End With
                
End Sub
```

Comment: A section break should only be inserted if you are making changes that affect page layout. A section break should not be used, under any circumstance, simply to add a new page.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt  What other purpose does a section break serve if not to allow a new section that starts on a new page.  Manual page breaks are the Devil's work and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @freeflow Section breaks greatly increase the complexity of a document. Manual page breaks are better, but still not that good. The best method for starting a new page is page-break-before formatting in the style of the paragraph that starts the new page. Section breaks are a very poor choice to start a new page. This was suggested by macropod in a comment to the question. http://www.addbalance.com/word/MovePages.htm

Comment: I get idea behind code, but modifying to my needs, I cant get .LinkToPrevious to work.     With Wapp
        With .Selection
            'New paragraph & line
            .TypeParagraph
            .TypeText St1
            .TypeText St2
            'Collapses selection
            .Collapse Direction:=0 'Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            'New page
            .InsertBreak Type:=7 'Type:=wdPageBreak
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        End With
        .ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers(1).LinkToPrevious = False
    End With

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to severely disagree with Macropod and CharlesKenyon.

Comment: Don't use a naked Selection, always assign the selection to a range and work with that.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "naked selection"?

Comment: Try  '.Selection.Range.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious'

Comment: A section break should ***only*** be used when the page layout changes, e.g. changing paper size, portrait to landscape, page number format, header or footer changes. Adding a section simply to force text onto a new page is a very bad practice. The ***only*** valid circumstance would be if it was necessary to use an Odd Page or Even Page break to allow for duplex printing.

Comment: @MatissZuravlevs - `LinkToPrevious` is invalid in the first section as there is no previous section to link to.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I totally disagree.  Sections are for organising content.

Comment: LinkToPrevious is invalid in the first section as there is no previous section to link to - Stupid me (sigh).

Comment: No they're not. *Heading styles* are for organizing content, sections are for page layout.

Comment: Then, as I said above, we will have to disagree.